# Displaying sort by id number

Tags: javascript, sorting

I manage to sort the products but it is display in a incorrect order shown here. It is using the list shown below.

[image: console output].

Why does it not go according to the id number? How to amend this code?

javascript

```js
  const product = {
  "medicine": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bioderma",
    "price": 5000,
    "imgName": "product_01.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Chanca Piedra",
    "price": 2300,
    "imgName": "product_02.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Umcka",
    "price": 4000,
    "imgName": "product_03.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "CetylPure",
    "price": 8700,
    "imgName": "product_04.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "CLACORE",
    "price": 5600,
    "imgName": "product_05.png"
  }
]
}
const sortByDefault = () => { product.medicine.sort((a, b) =>  a.id - b.id)}
sortByDefault()
console.log(product.medicine)
```

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I tested your exact code on code snippet and even on the browser's console, it works fine, Which environment do you use?

Comment: I test it on google. I using nodejs and ejs

Comment: The code in your snippet works fine. There must be something else, or maybe you forgot to save your file.

Comment: Well I save and refresh even close and reopen application and browser but it still shows me the picture.

Comment: I just realise it is because I have a similar code to sortDefault but is for price. I believe the two function clash hence I keep seeing the output of the price one instead of sortDefault. However on another note, how do I rename the output for console.log?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `return` in your `sortByDefault` function. It should be:

```
const sortByDefault = () => { return product.medicine.sort((a, b) =>  a.id - b.id)}
// or like this:
// const sortByDefault = () => product.medicine.sort((a, b) =>  a.id - b.id)

//and store it in some variable
    const sortedValue = sortByDefault()
    console.log(sortedValue)
```

Comment: The [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function sorts the array in-place, there is no need to return

Comment: @Seblor Removing `'return` will return just `undefined` whereas adding `return` produces desired results. Here is an example: https://replit.com/@AnasAnsariJobs/sortingjs

Comment: There is no need to return nor to reassign the variable. The `sort` call will edit the array by itself (thus "in-place")

Comment: It looks weird because the original poster used {} to encapsulate a one-line arrow function, therefore it doesn't have the implicit return. So yes, it does need to be returned to the correct scope, otherwise the 'sort in place' exists only in the function scope and is discarded. That said, there's no reason to put the sort method inside of another function instead of just calling it on the scope that OP wants.